# wcf System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException

Tags: wcf, httpcfg.exe

Apologies if this question appears twice on stackOverflow

Im trying to run a wcf service on a windows server 2003 box. Im getting a **System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException** exception when the servicehost calls Open() and it tells gives me the following error:

> HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/LogoResizer/mex/ because TCP port 8080 is being used by another application

Ive read that I need to use the httpcfg.exe to register my namespace and Ive used the GUI tool found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx) to do it but I still get the above exception. Running "netstat -a" doesnt show anything else listening on port 8080 and running "httpcfg.exe query urlacl" returns me the following registered namespaces.

> C:\Program Files\Support Tools>httpcfg query urlacl
>       URL : http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/
>
> ### ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

```
URL : http://+:8080/LogoResizer/
```

### ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

```
URL : http://+:8080/LogoResizer/mex/
```

### ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

The config for my app is as below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ImageResizerServiceContract" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>

        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="LogoResizer.WCF.ServiceTypes.ImageResizerService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:900/mex/"/>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ImageResizerServiceContract" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="LogoResizer.WCF.ServiceContracts.IImageResizerService" />
            <endpoint  address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Does anyone have any idea what Im doing wrong or how I can register my namespace so I can have a http endpoint for my service?

Comment: "Apologies if this question appears twice on stackOverflow". You mean, System.StackOverflow.QuestionAlreadyInUseException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked it out.

Problem was having both my endpoints running off the same port. This isnt an issue when developing under windows XP, but will give you the exceptions I wrote about when trying to  run the service under Vista or windows server 2003. I just needed to update my server config to the following

```
   <baseAddresses>
                                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/mex/"/>
                                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/" />
                            </baseAddresses>
```